# Python. Подсчет количества чего-либо, что имеет одинаковое имя

Tags: python, парсер, словари

К примеру, есть список \ кортеж строк:

---

```
("2014-01-01 01:12:13 181",
 "2014-01-02 20:11:10 600",
 "2014-01-03 01:12:13 6009",
 "2014-01-03 12:13:55 200")
```

---

Нужно посчитать сумму значений, что отделены последним пробелом, по каждому дню (по значениям, отделенным первым пробелом), **но как можно короче**.

Я знаю, как это сделать, но мне кажется, можно использовать меньше строчек для этого. Mой вариант:

```
def total_cost(calls):
    cost = dict()
    for i in calls:
        i = i.split()
        cost[i[0]] = cost.get(i[0], 0) + int(i[2])
    return cost

print(total_cost(("2014-01-01 01:12:13 181",
                  "2014-01-02 20:11:10 600",
                  "2014-01-03 01:12:13 6009",
                  "2014-01-03 12:13:55 200")))
```

**Итак, возможно ли короче?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так поробовать:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [(a,sum(map(lambda x: int(x.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]), b)))
       for a,b in groupby(lst, lambda x: x.split()[0])]
```

Результат:

```
In [57]: print(res)
[('2014-01-01', 181), ('2014-01-02', 600), ('2014-01-03', 6209)]
```

---

или еще чуть короче:

```
res = [(a,sum(map(lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), b)))
       for a,b in groupby(lst, lambda x: x.split()[0])]
```

---

Вот гораздо более элегантное решение от [@YuriM1983](https://toster.ru/q/515023):

```
from collections import Counter

a = ("2014-01-01 01:12:13 181", "2014-01-02 20:11:10 600",
     "2014-01-03 01:12:13 6009",  "2014-01-03 12:13:55 200")

cost = sum((Counter({x.split()[0]: int(x.split()[-1])}) for x in a), Counter())
```

Результат:

```
In [68]: print(cost)
Counter({'2014-01-03': 6209, '2014-01-02': 600, '2014-01-01': 181})

In [69]: print(dict(cost))
{'2014-01-01': 181, '2014-01-02': 600, '2014-01-03': 6209}
```

Comment: Если интересно, то тут есть еще один вариант реализации: [toster](https://toster.ru/q/515023)

Comment: @Mr_Pod, спасибо! Вариант с `Counter` - гораздо красивее...

Comment: выглядит это ужасно.  Совершенно нечитаемо. Даже исходный вариант в вопросе лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Для подсчёта, как часто элементы в коллекции встречаются, удобно [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) использовать:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for line in calls:
    date, _, cost = line.rpartition(' ')
    counter[date] += int(cost)
```

Не стоит пытаться умять код в одну  строчку, если это делает код менее читаемым. Но если хочется любой ценой получить однострочник:

```
>>> {date: int(cost) for line in calls for date, _, cost in [line.rpartition(' ')]}
{'2014-01-01 01:12:13': 181,
 '2014-01-02 20:11:10': 600,
 '2014-01-03 01:12:13': 6009,
 '2014-01-03 12:13:55': 200}
```

это предполагает что даты не повторяются.

Comment: Спасибо, @jfs! Как же много в Питоне полезных модулей...